# PHP network copy - failed to open stream, permission denied, but works from console

Tags: php, windows, networking, printing, permissions

I have a shared printer on my network (USB printer that is shared) and when I copy a file to it from console it is working and it gets printed. But when I do the same from a browser I get this error:

```
// I don't know why 4 backsladhes but it works from console
copy('C:\Users\Liga\testfile', '\\\\TOM-PC\epsons');
```

> Warning: copy(\TOM-PC\epsons): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\net-print.php on line 2

[image]

It seems to me that when I run this command from console then PHP has permissions to access the network device but when PHP is running from the browser then it doesn't have permissions. How could I fix this?

Comment: PHP-CLI (command line) may have different config from PHP-FPM (apache, nginx). `copy()`  could be disabled in your PHP-FPM config for security reasons

Comment: copy() is not disabled on apache, I tested  and it works with ````copy('C:\Users\Liga\testfile', 'C:\Users\Liga\testfile2');````

Comment: If you run your web server with a local [service account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/service-user-accounts) it won't have access to network resources.

Comment: But how do I run my Apache server and give it all access to network resources?

Comment: Oh, I see. I had to open ````services.msc```` then find Apache and change the Log On and make it log on from .\Administrator account. Now it's working.